# Getting 'owner' bean in redbean php

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, redbean

Say I have

```
$book = R::dispense( 'book' );

$page = R::dispense( 'page' );
R::store($page);

$book->ownPage[] = $page;
R::store($book);
```

Given a 'page' bean is it possible find its owning book other than executing some SQL where I look for the book_id property of the page on the book table?

something like:

```
$page->owningBook();
```

Currently I use this code:

```
    $owningBook = R::load('book', $page->book_id);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe, and I am 90% sure on this, you can just do:

```
$page->book->_______
```

I use something similar in my code:

```
$companys->ownEmployees=array($employee);
```

Then when I view the employee by itself I use:

```
$company=$employee->company;
```

Give it a shot and let me know.

**Edit: 100% Thanks!**

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I'm sure I tried that and got an exception, but maybe I did something wrong!

Comment: As the original author of RedBeanPHP I can tell you this is also the way it is meant to work. So let's make that 100% ;)